# How to write Text in different colors in single word in windows phone?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

[image]

Like the above image, I want to change the color of the text int the windows phone, either by cs file or by the xaml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In XAML, you define a `TextBlock` that contains multiple `Run` elements with different colors, like this:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="S">
        <Run.Foreground>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="#DEFF6767" />
        </Run.Foreground>
    </Run>
    <Run Text="a">
        <Run.Foreground>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="#DEDCFF00" />
        </Run.Foreground>
    </Run>
    <Run Text="m">
        <Run.Foreground>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="#DE002EFF" />
        </Run.Foreground>
    </Run>
    <Run Text="p">
        <Run.Foreground>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="#DEFF00D1" />
        </Run.Foreground>
    </Run>
    <Run Text="l">
        <Run.Foreground>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="#DE97FF00" />
        </Run.Foreground>
    </Run>
    <Run Text="e">
        <Run.Foreground>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="#DEB507D1" />
        </Run.Foreground>
    </Run>
</TextBlock>
```

Alternatively, here is how you do in C#:

```
TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = "S", Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red) });
textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = "a", Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue) });
textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = "m", Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow) });
textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = "p", Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange) });
textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = "l", Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray) });
textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = "e", Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green) });
```